# Error in creating new docker image from my project file

Tags: c#, docker, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2017

On my windows 10 machine, when I am trying to create a docker image of my solution/project it is giving me following error (this is full log, error is at the end)

```
Sending build context to Docker daemon  1.363MB
Step 1/20 : FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:2.1-stretch-slim AS base
---> bbfbcd874370
Step 2/20 : WORKDIR /app
---> Using cache
---> 6aa13d5c0c78
Step 3/20 : EXPOSE 80
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 80df41e66b51
Step 4/20 : EXPOSE 443
 ---> Using cache
 ---> e6b48dd0ebe8
Step 5/20 : FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:2.1-stretch AS build
 ---> 83e4b70d6dc1
Step 6/20 : ARG BuildConfiguration=Release
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 1f78c91d39f1
Step 7/20 : WORKDIR /src
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 213aa5f648e4
Step 8/20 : COPY ["NuGet.config", "."]
 ---> Using cache
 ---> d8843fccc7af
Step 9/20 : COPY ["MyProj.csproj", "ServiceProject/"]
 ---> Using cache
 ---> af245be6312e
Step 10/20 : RUN dotnet restore  --configfile NuGet.config "MyProj.csproj"
 ---> Running in 0582b332eab7
MSBUILD : error MSB1009: Project file does not exist.
Switch: MyProj.csproj
The command '/bin/sh -c dotnet restore  --configfile NuGet.config "MyProj.csproj"' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

**Dockerfile** is as follows

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:2.1-stretch-slim AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:2.1-stretch AS build
ARG BuildConfiguration=Release
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["NuGet.config", "."]
COPY ["MyProj.csproj", "NewProj/"]
RUN dotnet restore  --configfile NuGet.config "MyProj.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/MyService"
RUN dotnet build "MyProj.csproj" -c ${BuildConfiguration} -o /app --no-restore

FROM build AS publish
ARG BuildConfiguration=Release
RUN dotnet publish "MyProj.csproj" -c ${BuildConfiguration} -o /app --no-restore

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "MyProj.dll"]
```

the file MyProj.csproj is present in the folder
Yes, I am running powershell in AdminMode
I also tried by giving full path, that also didn't work

I tried docker documentation and stackoverflow but there is no mention of this error. Please provide step by step solution if possible, thanks in advance

Comment: I think you are copying "MyProj.csproj" to "NewProj/" folder, but then trying to use it as if it was in ".", same as your nuget.config

Comment: Thanks, I tried to copy csproj file to "." now it is giving
/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/2.1.801/NuGet.targets(525,5): error : Value cannot be null or empty string. [/src/MyProj.csproj]
/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/2.1.801/NuGet.targets(525,5): error : Parameter name: username [/src/MyProj.csproj]

Comment: And this one means that your nuget feed requires username/password authentication. You can add them to your nuget.config (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/nuget-config-file#package-source-sections)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To put my comments as an answer - your initial problem is with the location of the csproj file. You run

```
COPY ["NuGet.config", "."]
COPY ["MyProj.csproj", "NewProj/"]
```

Therefore MyProj.csproj is located at "NewProj/". So when you run

```
RUN dotnet restore  --configfile NuGet.config "MyProj.csproj"
```

MyProj cannot be found. Options are to provide a correct path to your project file or to copy it to the same location as nuget.config.

As for your following error - seems like

> /usr/share/dotnet/sdk/2.1.801/NuGet.targets(525,5): error : Value cannot be null or empty string. [/src/MyProj.csproj]
>
> /usr/share/dotnet/sdk/2.1.801/NuGet.targets(525,5): error : Parameter
> name: username [/src/MyProj.csproj]

"username" is required to access one of nuget feeds you are using. Try adding username/password to your nuget.config file - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/nuget-config-file#package-source-sections